# Using moment.js to get number of days in current month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How would one use moment.js to get the number of days in the current month? Preferably without temporary variables.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Moment has a [`daysInMonth` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/):

> **Days in Month** 1.5.0+
>
> ```
> moment().daysInMonth();
> ```
>
> Get the number of days in the current month.
>
> ```
> moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 29
> moment("2012-01", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 31
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the days in an array

```
Array.from(Array(moment('2020-02').daysInMonth()).keys())
//=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...27, 28]

Array.from(Array(moment('2020-02').daysInMonth()), (_, i) => i + 1)
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...28, 29]
```

Answer (score 3):

To return days in an array you can also use

```
Array.from({length: moment('2020-02').daysInMonth()}, (x, i) => moment().startOf('month').add(i, 'days').format('DD'))

// ["01","02","03", "04", ... "28","29"]
```

Answer (score 0):

MomentJS can list days of the months.

```js
const daysofThisMonth = Array.from(Array(moment().daysInMonth()), (_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(daysofThisMonth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```