# Generate days of a month using Moment.js fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

```
const generateDatesOfAMonth = () => {

    let start_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-01"),
    end_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-") + moment().daysInMonth(),
    dayArray = [];

    while (start_date_of_month <= end_date_of_month) {
        dayArray.push({ days: start_date_of_month });
        start_date_of_month = moment(start_date_of_month).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dayArray;
}
```

What's wrong with my code above? We can know number of days of each month, I found a solution via moment, but is my loop wrong? I expect an array of days but what I got is only 1st day. Hmm, any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using moment.js to get number of days in current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553652/using-moment-js-to-get-number-of-days-in-current-month)

Comment: @ToanTran this doesn't return an array to me. I already did the get first and last day using moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date and Subtract days using Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651815/format-date-and-subtract-days-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

I think 
`start_date_of_month = moment(start_date_of_month).add(1, 'days');`

should be
`start_date_of_month = start_date_of_month.add(1, 'days');`

Check out this resource:
[Format date and Subtract days using Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651815/format-date-and-subtract-days-using-moment-js)

Comment: You should flag this question as a duplicate of that one rather than posting an answer. Someone else already did, it auto-generates a comment like "Possible duplicate of (link)".

Answer (score 0):

@AlenJenshen: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to comment your question. But there are the solution for your question:

```
const generateDatesOfAMonth = () => {

    let start_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-01"),
    end_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-") + moment().daysInMonth(),
    dayArray = [];


    while (start_date_of_month <= end_date_of_month) {
        dayArray.push({ days: start_date_of_month });
        start_date_of_month = moment(start_date_of_month).add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }
    return dayArray;
}
```

You forgot to format `start_date_of_month`, so while loop can not compare start_date to end_date. Please try my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[...Array(moment().daysInMonth()).keys()];` to build and array with an element for each day of the month (e.g. `[1, ... 31]`). Then you can use [`date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) and [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get your result.

Here a live working sample:

```js
const generateDatesOfAMonth = () => {
  // Get array of numbers for each day of the month
  let days = [...Array(moment().daysInMonth()).keys()];
  // Create a moment object for each day and format it
  let dayArray = days.map( day => { 
     return { days: moment().date(day+1).format('YYYY-MM-DD') } 
  });
  return dayArray;
}

console.log( generateDatesOfAMonth() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```