# Getting all the dates of a month when a date is provided using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date

I want to get all the dates of a month when a date is provided by the user. I am a newbie to angularjs. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: did you mean to say getting all dates of the month when MONTH is provided by any chance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553652/using-moment-js-to-get-number-of-days-in-current-month

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve this...

1. take a date as input from user;
2. calculate first and last dates of that month;
3. run a loop which gets all the dates in between and stores in an array;
4. print the array on screen

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.particularDate;
  $scope.relevantMonth;
  $scope.relevantYear;
  $scope.relevantFirstDate;
  $scope.relevantLastDate;


  $scope.calcDate = function() {
    if ($scope.selectedDate) {
      $scope.yearPart = $scope.selectedDate.toString().substring(11, 15);
      $scope.particularDate = new Date($scope.selectedDate.toString().substring(0, 10));
      $scope.particularDate.setYear($scope.yearPart);

      $scope.relevantMonth = $scope.particularDate.getMonth() + 1;
      $scope.relevantYear = $scope.particularDate.getFullYear();

      $scope.relevantLastDate = new Date($scope.relevantYear, $scope.relevantMonth, 0);
      $scope.relevantFirstDate = new Date($scope.relevantYear, $scope.relevantMonth - 1, 1);
      $scope.fillAllDays();
    }
  }

  $scope.fillAllDays = function() {
    $scope.monthArray = [];

    var t = $scope.relevantFirstDate;
    $scope.monthArray.push(t.toLocaleDateString());

    for (var i = $scope.relevantFirstDate.getDate(); i < $scope.relevantLastDate.getDate(); i++) {
      t.setDate(t.getDate() + 1);
      $scope.monthArray.push(t.toLocaleDateString());
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Date: <input type='date' ng-model='selectedDate' ng-change='calcDate()' /> <br>
  <hr/>
  <p ng-repeat='x in monthArray'>{{x}}</p>
</div>
```